# how to write a query for this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a query like this,

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, date)) + '-' + 
                        RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, date), 2) AS date 
FROM
    tblSample 
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, date)) + '-' + 
                        RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, date), 2) AS date 
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, date)) + '-' + 
                        RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, date), 2) AS date
```

I had data like this:

```
Apr-17
jan-16
jan-17
mar-17
```

I have a requirement that the output should order by year part which means all the '17' (year parts) data should be shown. Like that we have to use order by for year part only how can I do that?

Comment: Check my answer I have updated

Comment: Show your data with duplicate values as i have show in insert query, so we have better idea

Comment: @saibharath What's the datatype of `date`? date or datetime or varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just change your order by query as below, you include both month name and year in order by instead of just select year in order by clause

```
ORDER BY  RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, date), 2) AS date
```

If you wants to apply order on first year and then month then write query as below:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, [date]), 2) DESC, CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, [date]))
```

I have tried below data:

```
DECLARE @tblA AS TABLE(
    [date] date
)

INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES('01-Apr-2017')
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES('01-Jan-2016')
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES('01-Jan-2017')
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES('01-Mar-2017')

SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, [date])) + '-' + 
                        RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, [date]), 2) AS date
FROM @tblA ORDER BY YEAR([date]) DESC, MONTH([date])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: output should be  like all the months in 17(in order like jan,feb,march etc) and then all the months in 16(in order) like this @SandipPatel

Comment: In your question can you please also update output table like you have put for initial data

Comment: It only works when table dosen't have duplicates,if table contains duplicates this query doesn't work.Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(MONTH,date))+'-
'+right(DATENAME(YEAR,date),2) as date from 
tblSample 
order by YEAR([date]),MONTH([date])
```

Comment: output should be like all the months in 17(in order like jan,feb,march etc) and then all the months in 16(in order) like this @WojciechWojtulewski

Comment: above one wroked perfectly thanks @Wojciech Wojtulewski

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(MONTH,date))+'-'+right(DATENAME(‌​
YEAR,date),2) as date,YEAR([date]) as year,MONTH([date]) as month from 
tblSample order by YEAR([date]) desc,MONTH([date])
```